# How to implement security filter predicate on detail tables in SQL Server 2016

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Find an example below of how we implement security filter predicate in SQL Server 2016. We have root tables on which we apply security rules and we want to rules to apply to detail/child tables. For example, if a sales rep create an order made of many shipments which contains many items, we don't want another sales rep to query those items.

```
USE [TestSecurity2016b]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OrderDetails]    Script Date: 2017-01-02 09:14:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesRep] [sysname] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderShipments]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TrackingNumber] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [ShippedOn] [Date] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderShipmentItems]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_OrderShipmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO 

insert dbo.Orders values 
    (1, 'SalesRep1'), 
    (2, 'SalesRep2');

insert dbo.[OrderShipments] values
(1, 1, '1234', '2016-12-25'),
(2, 1, '4321', '2016-12-26'),
(3, 2, '5678', '2017-01-01');

insert dbo.[OrderShipmentItems] values
(1, 1, 'Benq w1070', 1),
(2, 1, '#8 Stainless bolts', 4),
(3, 2, 'HP x360 Laptop', 1),
(4, 3, 'Nintendo NES', 1),
(5, 3, 'Intellivision', 1),
(6, 3, 'Coleco', 1);

GO 

create user Manager without login;
create user SalesRep1 without login;
create user SalesRep2 without login;

GO 

grant select on dbo.Orders to Manager;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipments] to Manager;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipmentItems] to Manager;

grant select on dbo.Orders to SalesRep1;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipments] to SalesRep1;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipmentItems] to SalesRep1;

grant select on dbo.Orders to SalesRep2;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipments] to SalesRep2;
grant select on dbo.[OrderShipmentItems] to SalesRep2;

GO 

create function dbo.fn_orderfilter_predicate(@SalesRep as sysname)
    returns table
with schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result 
where @SalesRep = user_name() or user_name() = 'Manager';

GO 

create function dbo.fn_ordershipmentsfilter_predicate(@FK_OrderID as int)
    returns table
with schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result 
    where @FK_OrderID in (select ID as OrdersID from dbo.Orders where SalesRep = user_name() or user_name() = 'Manager')

GO

create function dbo.fn_ordershipmentitemsfilter_predicate(@FK_OrderShipmentID as int)
    returns table
with schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result 
    where @FK_OrderShipmentID in 
    (
        SELECT    OrderShipments.ID AS OrderShipmentID
        FROM    dbo.Orders INNER JOIN
                dbo.OrderShipments ON Orders.ID = OrderShipments.FK_OrderID
        WHERE   (Orders.SalesRep = USER_NAME() OR USER_NAME() = 'Manager') 
                AND (OrderShipments.ID = @FK_OrderShipmentID) 
    )

GO

create security policy OrdersFilter
add filter predicate dbo.fn_orderfilter_predicate(SalesRep) 
on dbo.Orders
with (state = on);

GO

create security policy OrderShipmentsFilter
add filter predicate dbo.fn_ordershipmentsfilter_predicate(FK_OrderID) 
on dbo.OrderShipments
with (state = on);

GO

create security policy OrderShipmentItemsFilter
add filter predicate dbo.fn_ordershipmentitemsfilter_predicate(FK_OrderShipmentID) 
on dbo.OrderShipmentItems
with (state = on);

GO

execute as user = 'SalesRep1';
select * from dbo.Orders; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipments; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipmentItems; 
revert;

GO

execute as user = 'SalesRep2';
select * from dbo.Orders; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipments; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipmentItems; 
revert;

GO

execute as user = 'Manager';
select * from dbo.Orders; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipments; 
select * from dbo.OrderShipmentItems; 
revert;

GO
```

This presents a number of problems:
- As child level increases, complexity of predicate increases
- Changing the security rule on the root table requires changing the rules for all child tables.

Is there a way to solve those problems?

Thank you

Comment: You can use handle row policy with views (for example with combination with schema policy), but always with more types the complexity increases.

Comment: Is there a way to have the security predicate runs in the same context as the initial query? It seems that querying/joining other tables in the predicate doesn't get filtered by their respective security predicate.

Comment: It's not usual to handle security (row policy) via db engine. It's task for application. You can create table with rights/roles and handle connections and rights for data dynamicaly or create collection of procedures and add right to execute procedure and make selections and filters inside procedure.